# Can I use waitForReadyRead in a QThread that belongs to the mainthread?

Tags: multithreading, qt, qthread

I have a QThread that contains a QUDPsocket (socket is member not local to QThread::run(), maybe I should change that from what I am reading). This QThread is instantiated in my QMainWindow class ie the GUI thread(I am not calling move to thread). Is it still safe to use waitForReadyRead or do I absolutly need to instantiate the QThread in main.cpp or call moveToThread() for it to be thread safe. I am getting intermittent double free exception inside the call to waitForReadyRead in the present way of doing it(sometimes I dont get it for days sometimes after 3 minutes).

Comment: up to now it seems that no.  You can probably call it from a QAction event but not form a QThread residing inthe main thread.

Comment: Do you call waitForBla() within the QThreads run method?

Comment: yes i do use it from there but before I did moveToThread(this) the QThread was actually still residing inside the main thread which made waitForBla generate a double free exception once in a while

Comment: But I must admit I also made another change simultaneously and that was to declare the QUdpSocket inside the run method instead of the class and adding a parent to it instead of no parent.(this was legacy code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Qt documentation](http://file:///opt/qtsdk-2009.05/qt/doc/html/qudpsocket.html) for `QUdpSocket`. There is a note there explaining the class is *reentrant*. Also from the [Qt documentation](http://file:///opt/qtsdk-2009.05/qt/doc/html/threads-reentrancy.html#reentrant):

> ...a class is said to be reentrant if its member functions can be called safely from multiple threads, as long as each thread uses a different instance of the class.

Thus, to answer your question, it does not really matter what the parent of the `QThread` is, as long as you make sure that the `QUdpSocket` instance you are using is instantiated within the context of the thread you are using it in.

Comment: Even by putting QUdpSocket as a class member of the QThread it still wasnt enough to get rid of the intemrittent double free exception it was genrating inside he call to waitForReadyRead()

Comment: Where do you construct the `QUdpSocket` object? Constructing it in the constructor of the thread is not enough as the constructor runs in the context of the main thread. You need to construct it in the `run()` method itself.